# Error in filling area, despite geometry is present

Tags: google-fusion-tables

despite I have a list of kml areas in a google fusion table (all the world's countries' boundaries), at some levels of zoom some countries are empty (not filled). If I zoom, they get filled, at least partially. How to overcome this error/bug?

[Link to the map](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1Kf2WQEHNA7iRKa2aiqIo_PD9O14C4PjtKAELf30)

Regards,

Elisa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than 500 features on a map, zooming out after a certain zoom level all polygons become dots on the map. That is by design and no workaround can be applied. 
See "Limits" section on [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables)

If you're zooming back in and see partially filled areas, that's because map tiles are not yet loaded into Google Map's cache. Once you put this map on a web page, this will get resolved. Reload the page after a couple of seconds to avoid it. See [Fusion Tables troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/troubleshooting)